# Creating a lookup table from a column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, xpath

I have a table in SQL Server that contains an `ID` and also a column with multiple values separated by a comma (like the example below)

```
ID        Category_number
-------------------------
1           3,5,6,8
2            4,8,23
3           4,7,5,3
```

I need to make this into a lookup table with 1 category number per row, so like below;

```
ID        Category_Number
-------------------------
1               3
1               5
1               6
```

I have been told that XPATH might be the solution to this. Does anyone have any sample code that will do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you normalize your table?

Comment: Who told you this had anything to do with XPath? I guess you could use it, but I don't see any XML anywhere!

Comment: @FrancisAvila, I know XPath can be used as a hack to go from a normalized table to a comma-delimited string, although that's not its intended purpose. It's possible it could help you go the other way, although I'm not sure how you'd do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this answer [Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-reco/314917#314917)

Create that function in your database.

Then you can create the results you want using:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    A.S Category_Number
FROM
    MyCsvTable
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split (',', MyCsvTable.Category_Number) A
```

Comment: @user1016171 I noticed that and edited the answer. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 2):

I know you just accepted the solution, but assuming you're using SQL Server, here is an alternative approach without building a function:

```
 SELECT A.[id],  
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Cat  
       FROM  
          (SELECT [id],  
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Cat, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
          FROM  YourTable
      ) AS A 
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

And some Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf427/3

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check HierarchyID in SQL SERVER. Some tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37171/HierarchyID-Data-Type-in-SQL-Server-2008

Basically all you need to do is to loop through string and find position of commas and replace them with chr(13) or such. In Oracle it can be done easily in a single query. I think the same can be done using HierarchyID in SQL Server starting from 2008 or maybe even earlier versions.